# Laravel & Mailgun: Guzzle not found in production

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, mailgun, guzzle

I decided to use Mailgun for my latest Laravel project since it seemed like there was great integration out of the box.

I followed the Laravel guide (http://laravel.com/docs/mail#configuration) on setting up Mailgun  and everything works locally. I'm able to send emails when running a local server in Vagrant but as soon as I attempt to send an email from my DigitalOcean server, I receive the following errors:

```
file: "/home/forge/MYPROJECTSITE.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php"
line: 121
message: "Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found"
type: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException"
```

I've tried reinstalling Guzzle and I've triple-checked all of my settings. The odd thing is that I receive emails when it's running from Vagrant but not when it's running from the DigitalOcean server.

Has anyone seen this or have any idea what settings could be causing this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you run Composer install or update on your DigitalOcean droplet to import the Guzzle vendor package?

Comment: I'm using Laravel Forge and `composer install` is in the deployment script. I SSH'ed into the server, however, and when I ran `composer install` I received the following: "Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them." When I run `composer update`  I receive: "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution:**

Remove the `composer.lock` line from `.gitignore` and push. After `composer install` your server will download the required dependencies using the lock file.

Comment: I almost had a 3AM meltdown over this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen to me on a new ubuntu box.. i couldnt for the life of me find out why since Guzzle was working in another spot.. I just changed the mail to SMTP and used the login/password from mailgun and it works.

Comment: Thanks for this Phil. I did the same (added username & password of my mailgun account) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k

mkswap /swapfile

swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: Probably should add some detail as to what these commands do and why they might work